# error NETSDK1005: Assets file doesn't have a target for 'netcoreapp3.1'

Tags: visual-studio-2022, target-framework, netcoreapp3.1

Trying to use AWS Toolkit to publish Lambda functions using VS 2022 and C#.  Builds OK, but publish throws this error.  Current TragetFramework is set to net6.0.  I tried deleting obj and bin folders, but no help.  I do have VS 2019 installed on the same machine and not sure if that is interfering in any way.  NuGet Manager version is 6.2.0

error NETSDK1005: Assets file doesn't have a target for 'netcoreapp3.1'. Ensure that restore has run and that you have included 'netcoreapp3.1' in the TargetFrameworks for your project

Comment: Did you resolve this issue?  Some colleagues of mine are having the same problem and I'm not sure how to help

Answer (score 2):

In my case it was just a matter of deleting the publish profile and creating a new one.

Comment: You just saved my sanity after weeks of trying to figure out what's wrong with my restore / msbuild and god knows what. Indeed, creating a new publish profile solved my issue